# Parse Javascript Calling Cloud Code functions from within another Cloud Code function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to do double method chaining in Parse javascript API

```
exports.getUserGifts = function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('getObjects', {
      success: function(results) {
          Parse.Cloud.run('getGifts', {
            success: function(results) {
                response.success(results);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.error("Some error.");
            }
          });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          response.error("Some error.");
      }
    });

}
```

but I am getting error

```
{"code":141,"error":"success/error was not called"}
```

Any help where I am doing the things wrong in above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

3 parameters (functionName, parameters, opts) are required by Parse.Cloud.run where as I was only passing 2 (functionName, opts) Now I have changed my code to

```
exports.getUserGifts = function (request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('getObjects',{}, {
      success: function(results) {
          Parse.Cloud.run('getGifts',{}, {
            success: function(results) {
                response.success(results);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.error("Some error.");
            }
          });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          response.error("Some error.");
      }
    });

}
```

and it is working fine.